# How to get string and byte to compare?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new to Arduino and c++ coding, I have been working on this project all day and I'm getting nowhere. I'm trying to compare the results from the RFID reader to the results coming from the database but I keep getting an error.

I have tried many different ways of fixing this but the firebase libary doesn't  have the `getbyte` function.

```
int UID1 = 2;
int UID2 = 2;
int UID3 = 2;
int UID4 = 2;
int UID5 = 2;
int UID6 = 2;

byte nuidPICC[4];

constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = 5; // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = 4;  // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Instance of the class
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

// Init array that will store new NUID

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();     // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522

  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println('\n');

  wifiConnect();

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

  delay(10);
}

void loop() {

  // Look for new cards
  if (!rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;

  // Verify if the NUID has been readed
  if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;

  Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
  MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);
  Serial.println(rfid.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

  // Check is the PICC of Classic MIFARE type
  if (piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI &&
      piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K &&
      piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_4K) {
    Serial.println(F("Your tag is not of type MIFARE Classic."));
    return;
  }

  if (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] != nuidPICC[0] ||
      rfid.uid.uidByte[1] != nuidPICC[1] ||
      rfid.uid.uidByte[2] != nuidPICC[2] ||
      rfid.uid.uidByte[3] != nuidPICC[3]) {
    Serial.println(F("A new card has been detected."));

    // Store NUID into nuidPICC array
    for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      nuidPICC[i] = rfid.uid.uidByte[i];
    }

    Serial.println(F("The NUID tag is:"));
    Serial.print(F("UID: "));
    printDec(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Card read previously."));
  }
  // Halt PICC
  rfid.PICC_HaltA();
  // Stop encryption on PCD
  rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();

  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID1") + "\n");
  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID2") + "\n");
  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID3") + "\n");
  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID4") + "\n");
  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID5") + "\n");
  Serial.print(Firebase.getString("UID6") + "\n");

  analogWrite(UID1, Firebase.getString("UID1").toInt());
  analogWrite(UID2, Firebase.getString("UID2").toInt());
  analogWrite(UID3, Firebase.getString("UID3").toInt());
  analogWrite(UID4, Firebase.getString("UID4").toInt());
  analogWrite(UID5, Firebase.getString("UID5").toInt());
  analogWrite(UID6, Firebase.getString("UID6").toInt());
  delay(3000);

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    wifiConnect();
  }
  delay(10);

  if (Firebase.getString("UID1") = rfid.uid.uidByte()) {
    Serial.print("Match")
  }
}
```

Here is my error:

> fireabse-alpha1:118:22: error: incompatible types in assignment of 
>     'String' to 'byte [10] {aka unsigned char [10]}'
>
> if (rfid.uid.uidByte = Firebase.getString("UID1")) {
>                          ^
>      fireabse-alpha1:120:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token
>
> }
>       ^

Comment: `rfid.uid.uidByte = Firebase.getString("UID1")` this is an assignment, not a comparison (==)

Comment: Moreover uidByte seem to be a function, replace `rfid.uid.uidByte` by `rfid.uid.uidByte()`

Comment: @Fareanor From its use in, for example, `rfid.uid.uidByte[1] != nuidPICC[1]`, it seems to be an array.

Comment: Nitpick: Your code could benefit from a healthy dose of [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ah ok, I just said that because in his code he called it as a function too.

Comment: _error: incompatible types in assignment of 'String' to 'byte [10] {aka unsigned char [10]}'_ indeed it is an array

Comment: @Fareanor i have tried both your tips and still nothing, i have a rfid code coming in and data from a database coming in and i want to compare them, am i doing it correctly or am i way off

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.println('\n');` is not needed. Because the `ln` in the name means that it wil print a newline.

`rfid.uid.uidByte` is a array of [10 bytes](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.h#L322).
`Firebase.getString("UID1")` [returns](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/firebase-arduino/latest/firebase-arduino.pdf#page=7) a arduino [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/)

You can't compare an array to a `String`. But you can compare the elements of a `String` to the elements of an array.

```
String handle = Firebase.getString("UID1");
uint8_t lengthToCompare = rfid.uid.size;
if(handle.length() != lengthToCompare){ // this only works if you compare the whole string
    // not equal
}

bool equal = true;
for(int i=0;i<lengthToCompare;++i) {
    equal &= handle.c_str()[i] == rfid.uid.uidByte[i]; // compare if equal and variable 
                                                       // equal remains true if so
}
// equal now holds if the sequences where equal
```

As said before `rfid.uid.uidByte = Firebase.getString("UID1")` is not a comparison but a assignment, and a bad one at that because a `String` is being assigned to a array of bytes. The comparison operator is `==`.

Also when posting on StackOverflow (or working with your code): [`clang-format.exe -i <filename>`](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) is your friend. (assuming you are using windows of course, I wouldn't want to presume your OS preferences)

Comment: thanks you for all your help but its not returning anything in my work. i have a UID in my database (209 110 242 32) and i am trying to pull that data and match it if the correct rfid card is read with the same number.

Comment: would it be possible to make rfid.uid.uidByte into a string ie just 20911024232 and then i could easyily see if they match and display a green LED

Comment: @CallumJackson Yes but only with an additional allocation that you don't really need